# Using ContourPlot to fill x < 300 with red and x > 300 with green

Tags: plotting

How do I fill left part of x=300 straight line with red colour and right part with green colour?

```
ContourPlot[x == 300, {x, 90 Pi, 150 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[x, {x, 90 Pi, 150 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, Contours -> {300}, ContourShading -> {Red, Green}]`

Comment: It worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Show[
  ContourPlot[x==300,{x,90 Pi,150 Pi},{y,0,4 Pi}],
  Plot[4 Pi,{x,90 Pi,300},PlotRange->{0,4 Pi},Filling->Axis,FillingStyle->Red],
  Plot[4 Pi,{x,300,150 Pi},PlotRange->{0,4 Pi},Filling->Axis,FillingStyle->Green]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]